# How do I pre-determine mutually exclusive comparisons?

Tags: r, algorithm

The human eye can see that no value x satisfies the condition

```
x<1 & x>2
```

but how can I make R see that. I want to use this in a function which gets passed comparisons (say as strings) and not necessarily data. Let's say I want to write a function that checks whether a combination of comparisons can ever be fulfilled anyway, like this

```
areTherePossibleValues <- function(someString){
    someCode
}

areTherePossibleValues("x<1 & x>2")
[1] FALSE
```

I mean one could do that by interpreting the substrings that are comparison signs and so on, but I feel like there's got to be a better way. The R comparison functions ('<','>','=' and so on) themselves actually might be the answer to this, right?

Comment: This is a fairly complex topic that requires you to create an algorithm that performs symbolic analysis of the expression and creates a truth table for lazy intervals. This requires being able to encode intervals symbolically and to apply equivalent transformations of boolean terms (look up De Morgan’s laws), followed by reduction. Modern optimising compilers are performing this kind of analysis.

Comment: See also: [automated theorem proving](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving).

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://github.com/data-cleaning/lintools and/or https://github.com/data-cleaning/editrules. I don't have enough experience with these packages to know for certain that these solve your problem and to write up an answer.

Comment: Can you put some constraints on the problem? For example, only constants on the right hand side.

Comment: This is not too complex if you limit to one variable, constrain comparisons to have the variable on the left, and limit to `<` and `>` comparisons and `&` operator. You'd just check if the min of the constants in `<`s is greater than the max of the constants in `>`s. Allowing `>=`, `<=`, and `=` might not be too much more complex. But relaxing other constraints, or trying to do it in full generality is difficult. Adding `|` (or) for instance, you'll need to define precedence of operators.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another option is to use the library `validatetools` (disclaimer, I'm its author).

```
library(validatetools)

rules <- validator( r1 = x < 1, r2 = x > 2)
is_infeasible(rules)
# [1] TRUE

make_feasible(rules)
# Dropping rule(s): "r1"
# Object of class 'validator' with 1 elements:
#  r2: x > 2
# Rules are evaluated using locally defined options

# create a set of rules that all must hold:
rules <- validator( x > 1, x < 2, x < 2.5)
is_infeasible(rules)
# [1] FALSE

remove_redundancy(rules)
# Object of class 'validator' with 2 elements:
#  V1: x > 1
#  V2: x < 2

rules <- validator( x >= 1, x < 1)
is_infeasible(rules)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

To compare among ranges, min of the range max(s) should always be greater than the max of the range min(s), showed as below:

```
library(dplyr)

library(stringr)

areTherePossibleValues <- function(s) {

  str_split(s, pattern = " *& *", simplify = TRUE)[1, ] %>% 

    {lapply(c("max" = "<", "min" = ">"), function(x) str_subset(., pattern = x) %>% str_extract(., pattern = "[0-9]+"))} %>% 

    {as.numeric(min(.$max)) > as.numeric(max(.$min))}

}
```

Update: add inclusion comparison

The only difference is that min of the range max(s) can be equal to the max of the range min(s).

```
library(dplyr)

library(stringr)

areTherePossibleValues <- function(s) {

  str_split(s, pattern = " *& *", simplify = TRUE)[1, ] %>% 

    {lapply(c("max" = "<", "min" = ">"), function(x) str_subset(., pattern = x) %>% str_remove(., pattern = paste0("^.*", x)))} %>% 

    {ifelse(sum(grepl(pattern = "=", unlist(.))), 

            as.numeric(min(str_remove(.$max, "="))) >= as.numeric(max(str_remove(.$min, "="))), 

            as.numeric(min(.$max)) > as.numeric(max(.$min)))}

}

areTherePossibleValues("x<1 & x>2")

areTherePossibleValues("x>1 & x<2")

areTherePossibleValues("x>=1 & x<1")
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way of solving it, it may not be the best, but it should work even you have many comparisons.

Let's call the numbers appeared in your comparisons 'cutoffs', then all we need to do is to test 1 number between each pair of cutoffs, 1 number that is larger than the max cutoff, and 1 number that is smaller than the min cutoff.

The intuition is illustrated with the plot:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
areTherePossibleValues <- function(s){

  # first get the numbers that appeared in your string, sort them, and call them the cutoffs
  cutoffs = sort(as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", strsplit(s,  "&")[[1]])))

  # get the numbers that in between each cutoffs, and a bit larger/smaller than the max/min in the cutoffs
  testers = (c(min(cutoffs)-1, cutoffs) + c( cutoffs ,max(cutoffs) + 1))/2

  # take out each comparisons
  comparisons = strsplit(s,  "&")[[1]]

  # check if ANY testers statisfy all comparisons
  any(sapply(testers, function(te){

    # check if a test statisfy ALL comparisons
    all(sapply(comparisons, function(co){eval(parse(text =gsub(pattern = 'x',replacement =te, co)))}))
  }))
}

areTherePossibleValues("x<1 & x>2")
#[1] FALSE

areTherePossibleValues("x>1 & x<2 & x < 2.5")
#[1] TRUE

areTherePossibleValues("x=> 1 & x < 1")
#[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

We see x<1 & x>2 is impossible because we are taught a simple rule: if a number *x* is smaller than another number *a* then it can not be bigger than another number that is bigger than *a*, or more fundamentally we are using the transitivity property of any partially ordered set. There is no reason we can not teach a computer (or R) to see that. If your logic string in your question only consists of statements in the forms x # a where # can be <, >, <=, and >=, and the operator is always &, then Yue Y's solution above perfectly answers your question. It can be even generalized to include the | operator. Beyond this you'll have to be more specific what the logic expression can be.